# Redrawing contents of Tabs in TabLayout / ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, invalidation, redraw, android-tablayout

My app has a TabLayout setup, with a ViewPager. There are 4 tabs. When a setting is changed all 4 tabs, and their internal Fragments need to all be redrawn as a significant amount of data changes within them. It does change with my current code after switching around to different tabs a few times. But it is not instant like it should be.

I am wondering if there is a method to redraw / invalidate the fragments instantly all at once.

I have tried:

- Resetting up the adapter / ViewPager
- Invalidating the ViewPager
- Resetting the customView for each tab

Nothing seems to work. I believe I am missing something or thinking about it the wrong way. Any help or suggestions which may help me find an answer would be greatly appreciated.

```
// inside onCreate method
adapter = new SectionPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, tabLayout, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tab_image);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[i]));
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        tab.setCustomView(view);
    }
    tabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();

// internal class
public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.d("Position", position + "");
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return tab;
            case 1:
                return tab1;
            case 2:
            default:
                return tab2;
            case 3:
                return tab3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        container.setTag(position);
        return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Drawable image = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(imageResId[position]);
        image.setBounds(0, 0, image.getIntrinsicWidth(), image.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString(" ");
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(image, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return sb;
    }
}
```